# How to put every variable in separate column with a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sparql

I want to make a table contain sparql results. that every variable of sparql query placed in separated column.

```
SparqlQueryParser par = new SparqlQueryParser();
SparqlQuery q = par.ParseFromString(@"Query");
object results = g.ExecuteQuery(q);

if (results is SparqlResultSet)
{
    SparqlResultSet rset = (SparqlResultSet)results;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (SparqlResult r in rset)
    {
        list.Add(r.ToString());
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = list;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: you never replied to your previous question, which is a shame as nobody will ever know if and how you solved the problem ... think about it ...

Comment: regarding your current question, it's really obvious, get all variables from the query or the resultset object and create the table columns. Why are you not using documentation: http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Query_SparqlResultSet.htm

Comment: Thank you for your replay... in previous question I do as you said because of that I didn't say anything!

Comment: Salim, you should say something because others who find the question won't know if it worked or not. This site is about more than just solving YOUR problem, it is about having the answers available to everybody who has the same problem.

Comment: sorry for that .. I'm new here. I reply to previous question